# Visual Studio: Attaching the Webkit debugger to process chrome.exe on machine failed

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

I have installed ***Visual Studio 15 Preview 5*** on my machine. Whenever I run a project with any browser other than ***Google Chrome*** it runs graciously. But whenever try to run with ***Google Chrome*** it cannot run the project stating as follows:

```
Attaching the Webkit debugger to process chrome.exe on machine "TanvirArjel" failed.
```

In the browser tab it shows as follows: [image]

Any idea how to fix this issue??

Comment: I'm having this same exact problem, chrome starts in a new window (not a new tab) and fails to attach. This happened when I installed safari for windows if that's a clue to anyone..

Comment: I have excactly the same issue in Preview 5 ...
I don't know why.
When I use other browser everything is ok. When I close this strange google chrome window (mistake shows in VS) and right click on ISS -> choose localhost, my solution runs properly...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Debug → Attach To Process, and change "Attach To:" to "Native Code".

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop debugging.
2. Edit csproj.user file
3. Find section wrote below:

> ```
> <SilverlightDebugging>True</SilverlightDebugging>
> ```

4. Change Value to "False"
5. Unload and reload your project in Visual Studio.
6. Sometimes it needed to close Visual Studio.